# Crear un carrousel manual y a la vez automático

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo mi carrousel, y no sé cómo puedo agregar diferentes textos en cada uno.
Lo que quiero es que por ejemplo: en una imagen diga "Lunes 20% de descuento", la siguiente diga "CiberFest" y todo así y poder darle su formato en *CSS*.
He mirado muchos tutoriales pero ninguno que me haya servido. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Variables
  const IMAGENES = [
    'https://cdn.autobild.es/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/bdc/dc/fotos/Ferrari-sf90-stradale.jpg?tf=3840x',
    'https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/facelift_2019/models_gw/2023/03_29_revuelto/gate_models_s_02_m.jpg',


  ];
  const TIEMPO_INTERVALO_MILESIMAS_SEG = 1000;
  let posicionActual = 0;
  let $botonRetroceder = document.querySelector('#retroceder');
  let $botonAvanzar = document.querySelector('#avanzar');
  let $imagen = document.querySelector('#imagen');

  let intervalo;

  // Funciones

  /**
   * Funcion que cambia la foto en la siguiente posicion
   */
  function pasarFoto() {
    if (posicionActual >= IMAGENES.length - 1) {
      posicionActual = 0;
    } else {
      posicionActual++;
    }
    renderizarImagen();
  }

  /**
   * Funcion que cambia la foto en la anterior posicion
   */
  function retrocederFoto() {
    if (posicionActual <= 0) {
      posicionActual = IMAGENES.length - 1;
    } else {
      posicionActual--;
    }
    renderizarImagen();
  }

  /**
   * Funcion que actualiza la imagen de imagen dependiendo de posicionActual
   */
  function renderizarImagen() {
    $imagen.style.backgroundImage = `url(${IMAGENES[posicionActual]})`;
  }



  // Eventos
  $botonAvanzar.addEventListener('click', pasarFoto);
  $botonRetroceder.addEventListener('click', retrocederFoto);

  // Iniciar
  renderizarImagen();
}
```

```css
/* Carrousel*/

#carrousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  background-color: rgb(172, 170, 170);
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#carrousel>#imagen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

button#retroceder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#retroceder,
#avanzar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.568);
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 20%;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#avanzar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(151, 112, 112);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.slider-inner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider>.slider-inner>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="carrousel">
  <button id="retroceder">
          Atras
            </svg>
        </button>
  <div id="imagen">
  </div>

  <button id="avanzar">
           Avanzar
        </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que ya resolviste el primer problema, para hacer que se deslice el carrusel manual y automáticamente puedes probar hacer algunos cambios en tu js. Tu código se vería así:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Variables
  const IMAGENES = [
    [
      'https://cdn.autobild.es/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/bdc/dc/fotos/Ferrari-sf90-stradale.jpg?tf=3840x', 
      'Lunes 20% de descuento'
    ],
    [
      'https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/facelift_2019/models_gw/2023/03_29_revuelto/gate_models_s_02_m.jpg',
      'CiberFest'
    ],
  ];
  const TIEMPO_INTERVALO_MILESIMAS_SEG = 1000;
  let posicionActual = 0;
  let $botonRetroceder = document.querySelector('#retroceder');
  let $botonAvanzar = document.querySelector('#avanzar');
  let $imagen = document.querySelector('#imagen');
  let $descripcion = document.querySelector('#descripcion');

  let intervalo;

  // Funciones

  function pasarFoto() {
    if (posicionActual >= IMAGENES.length - 1) {
      posicionActual = 0;
    } else {
      posicionActual++;
    }
    renderizarImagen();
  }

  function retrocederFoto() {
    if (posicionActual <= 0) {
      posicionActual = IMAGENES.length - 1;
    } else {
      posicionActual--;
    }
    renderizarImagen();
  }

  function renderizarImagen() {
    $imagen.style.backgroundImage = `url(${IMAGENES[posicionActual][0]})`;
    $descripcion.innerText = `${IMAGENES[posicionActual][1]}`
  }

  function iniciarCarruselAutomatico() {
    intervalo = setInterval(pasarFoto, 3000); // 3000 milisegundos = 3 segundos
  }

  function detenerCarruselAutomatico() {
    clearInterval(intervalo);
  }

  // Eventos
  $botonAvanzar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pasarFoto();
    detenerCarruselAutomatico();
  });
  $botonRetroceder.addEventListener('click', () => {
    retrocederFoto();
    detenerCarruselAutomatico();
  });

  // Iniciar carrusel automático al cargar la página
  iniciarCarruselAutomatico();

  // ...
}
```

```css
/* Carrousel*/

#carrousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  background-color: rgb(172, 170, 170);
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#carrousel>#imagen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

button#retroceder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#retroceder,
#avanzar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.568);
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 20%;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#avanzar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(151, 112, 112);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.slider-inner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider>.slider-inner>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#imagen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex: 1;
}

#descripcion {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="carrousel">
  <button id="retroceder">Atras</button>
  <div id="imagen">
    <p id="descripcion"></p>
  </div>
  <button id="avanzar">Avanzar</button>
</div>
```

En donde creé un intervalo, en el cual, cada 3 segundos se cambia de una imagen a otra, puedes ajustar esto según lo que desees. Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo, llevo demasiado tiempo sin programar que mi cerebro no se acuerda de nada y vengo por ayuda, Mil gracias me sirvio!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el principal problema es la estructura del html, sólo tienes un div que le cambias la imagen de fondo para el carrusel, una alternativa es tener un `div` con 2 elementos internos: 1 `img` y 1 `div` para el texto

```
<div class="container">
  <img id="imagen" src="imagen_a_cambiar.jpg" style="width:100%;">
  <div id="texto" class="centered" >texto_a_cambiar</div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Entonces en los eventos que ya tienes, cambiar el `src` del `img` y el `innerHtml` del `div` texto

Answer (score 0):

Propongo esta solución:

- Crear un array multidimensional que contenga las imágenes y el texto
- Acceder a cada elemento en cada iteración y modificar ambos valores

Adicionalmente, agregué algo de `CSS` para darle un poco de visibilidad al elemento `<p>`.

*Revisa en pantalla completa y comenta si tienes dudas adicionales.*

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Variables
  const IMAGENES = [
    [
      'https://cdn.autobild.es/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/bdc/dc/fotos/Ferrari-sf90-stradale.jpg?tf=3840x', 
      'Lunes 20% de descuento'
    ],
    [
      'https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/facelift_2019/models_gw/2023/03_29_revuelto/gate_models_s_02_m.jpg',
      'CiberFest'
    ],
  ];
  const TIEMPO_INTERVALO_MILESIMAS_SEG = 1000;
  let posicionActual = 0;
  let $botonRetroceder = document.querySelector('#retroceder');
  let $botonAvanzar = document.querySelector('#avanzar');
  let $imagen = document.querySelector('#imagen');
  let $descripcion = document.querySelector('#descripcion');

  let intervalo;

  // Funciones

  /**
   * Funcion que cambia la foto en la siguiente posicion
   */
  function pasarFoto() {
    if (posicionActual >= IMAGENES.length - 1) {
      posicionActual = 0;
    } else {
      posicionActual++;
    }
    renderizarImagen();
  }

  /**
   * Funcion que cambia la foto en la anterior posicion
   */
  function retrocederFoto() {
    if (posicionActual <= 0) {
      posicionActual = IMAGENES.length - 1;
    } else {
      posicionActual--;
    }
    renderizarImagen();
  }

  /**
   * Funcion que actualiza la imagen de imagen dependiendo de posicionActual
   */
  function renderizarImagen() {
    $imagen.style.backgroundImage = `url(${IMAGENES[posicionActual][0]})`;
    $descripcion.innerText = `${IMAGENES[posicionActual][1]}`
  }



  // Eventos
  $botonAvanzar.addEventListener('click', pasarFoto);
  $botonRetroceder.addEventListener('click', retrocederFoto);

  // Iniciar
  renderizarImagen();
}
```

```css
/* Carrousel*/

#carrousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  background-color: rgb(172, 170, 170);
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#carrousel>#imagen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

button#retroceder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#retroceder,
#avanzar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.568);
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 20%;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#avanzar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(151, 112, 112);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.slider-inner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider>.slider-inner>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#imagen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex: 1;
}

#descripcion {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="carrousel">
  <button id="retroceder">Atras</button>
  <div id="imagen">
    <p id="descripcion"></p>
  </div>
  <button id="avanzar">Avanzar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Me ayudo muchisimo, muchas gracias, ahora vere como lo puedo hacer que se deslize el carrousel solo, MUCHAAS GRACIAS